# Database Table move issues

Tags: sql-server

I want to move the structure of user defined tables and all the stored procedures and functions from old database to new database through a SQL query...

I created the database through an stored procedure it is worked fine, but it is not creating the tables inside the database

I tried with the following queries but it is not working and I don't know whether it is proper or not...

```
SELECT INSERT newdb..+name SELECT * FROM olddb..name FROM sys.tables
```

or can i use the below methods
select * into newDB.sys.tables from oldDB.sys.tables where type='U'

How can I achieve this...

Can anyone help me...?

Thank you...

Comment: i cant restore because the database name is different and i want only table strucures not the data

Comment: @Marc: thank you is there any way like select tables into new database from select tables from old database, because i want to do it in existing stored procedure

Comment: can i use like this select * into SHA.sys.tables from vb201314.sys.tables where type='U'

Answer (score 0):

i think easiest way to do this is to generate database script .

**[Here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/07/sql-server-2008-2008-r2-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-data-schema-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects/)** is a nice article about Generating Script from Database. just generate script using the given article and run it to your new DB. **Make sure you select "SCHEMA ONLY" option in "Types of data to script" while generating the script.**

PS : never try to do this if you want both data and schema on production it might cost quiet a bit resources which might slow down your websites.